# Sort XML into Sets and Elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have an xml document that contains set definitions and element definitions. Sample XML:

```
<!-- a set definition -->
<a name="SET.1" mnemonic="NAME_SET" ... />
<!-- an element definition -->
<a name="NAME_SET.1" mnemonic="Element1" .../>
```

I have no control over the xml that is coming in. The only way to tell the difference between a set definition and an element definition is by the value of the `name` attribute. In a set definition, it will start with "SET"; in an element definition, it will start with the value of the set's mnemonic attribute.

I'd like to do use XSLT to sort the file by set and then by elements within the set. Meaning:

```
<!-- a set definition -->
<a name="SET.1" mnemonic="ANIMAL_SET" ... />
<!-- an element definition -->
<a name="ANIMAL_SET.1" mnemonic="Mouse" .../>
... all the elements in ANIMAL_SET

<!-- a set definition -->
<a name="SET.2" mnemonic="VEHICLE_SET" ... />
<!-- an element definition -->
<a name="VEHICLE_SET.1" mnemonic="Car" .../>
... all the elements in VEHICLE_SET
```

I believe that to do this, I'd use `<xsl:for-each>`, but I'm not sure how. Any ideas?

Edited to add clearer explanation of my sample xml:

Original xml:

```
<ExternalTag attribute="00061000">
    <TagOnSameLevel attribute="foo"/>
    <a attribute="1" mnemonic="CAR_SET" name="SET.102" />
    <a attribute="3" mnemonic="Toyota" name="CAR_SET.3" />
    <a attribute="11" mnemonic="lion" name="ANIMAL_SET.12" />
    <a attribute="2" mnemonic="Chevy" name="CAR_SET.2" />
    <a attribute="2" mnemonic="ANIMAL_SET" name="SET.1034" />
    <a attribute="6" mnemonic="tiger" name="ANIMAL_SET.6" />
</ExternalTag>
```

Desired xml after xslt: SETs sorted by name with the elements in each set also sorted by name.

```
<ExternalTag attribute="00061000">
    <TagOnSameLevel attribute="foo"/>
    <a attribute="1" mnemonic="CAR_SET" name="SET.102" />
    <a attribute="2" mnemonic="Chevy" name="CAR_SET.2" />
    <a attribute="3" mnemonic="Toyota" name="CAR_SET.3" />
    <a attribute="2" mnemonic="ANIMAL_SET" name="SET.1034" />
    <a attribute="11" mnemonic="lion" name="ANIMAL_SET.12" />
    <a attribute="6" mnemonic="tiger" name="ANIMAL_SET.6" />
</ExternalTag>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="input/a[starts-with(@name, 'SET.')]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="../a[starts-with(@name, current()/@mnemonic)]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given a well-formed **test input**:

```
<input>
    <a name="SET.1" mnemonic="ANIMAL_SET"/>
    <a name="SET.2" mnemonic="VEHICLE_SET"/>
    <a name="ANIMAL_SET.1" mnemonic="Mouse" />
    <a name="VEHICLE_SET.1" mnemonic="Car"/>
    <a name="ANIMAL_SET.1" mnemonic="Cat" />
    <a name="VEHICLE_SET.1" mnemonic="Truck"/>
</input>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <a name="SET.1" mnemonic="ANIMAL_SET"/>
   <a name="ANIMAL_SET.1" mnemonic="Mouse"/>
   <a name="ANIMAL_SET.1" mnemonic="Cat"/>
   <a name="SET.2" mnemonic="VEHICLE_SET"/>
   <a name="VEHICLE_SET.1" mnemonic="Car"/>
   <a name="VEHICLE_SET.1" mnemonic="Truck"/>
</output>
```

A smarter form of output would wrap each group in a combining element.

---

### Edit

In view of your updated input, try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/ExternalTag">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *[not(self::a)] | a[starts-with(@name, 'SET.')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>   

<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="../a[starts-with(@name, current()/@mnemonic)]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Is there a way for me to do this without losing the surrounding xml structure? All my `a`s are surrounded by a different tag that has its own attributes that I don't want to lose.

Comment: @chama Please edit your question and add a [minimal but complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your input and the requested output.

Comment: It worked! I just needed a bit of tweaking to make it work with my real xml. Thanks!